# Selenium code to input values to text boxes from excel by opening browser single time

Tags: selenium

I wrote a selenium code to read values from an excel sheet which contains 2 columns.I need to input these to 2 text boxes in a webpage .I do not want to use TestNG at this point .My issue is every time the browser opens with the webpage for each entry ie each row  . Say I have 10 rows in the excel sheet 10 web pages are opened and each would input to the text boxes .How can I rewrite my code to open a single browser and input values one by one .

```
  public class Insert {
  public static void main(String[] args)

{   
try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("F:\\Book4.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

           XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("testdata");

        for(int count = 1;count<=sheet.getLastRowNum();count++)
        {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(count);
            System.out.println("Running test case " + row.getCell(0).toString());

            runTest(row.getCell(1).toString(),row.getCell(2).toString());

        }
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Test data file not found");
    }   
}

public static  void runTest(String name,String mailid) 
{
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.deal4loans.com/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/a[1]")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(name);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(mailid);


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the data is as below (**'--' is used as a separator for columns**):

```
NAME -- EMAIL-ID
Name1   -- www.email.com1
Name2   -- www.email.com2
Name3   -- www.email.com3
Name4   -- www.email.com4
Name5   -- www.email.com5
Name6   -- www.email.com6
```

Below code navigates to the browser once and enters in fields at an interval of 2 seconds. 

**[Works fine when tried with an xls file with "HSSFWorkbook" class]**

```
public class Insert {
    static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {   
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://www.deal4loans.com/");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/a[1]")).click();

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("F:\\Book4.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("testdata");

            for(int count=1;count<=sheet.getLastRowNum();count++)
            {
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(count);
                System.out.println("\n----------------------------");
                System.out.println("Running test case " + count);

                runTest(row.getCell(0).toString(),row.getCell(1).toString());

            }
            fis.close();
            driver.close();// Closing the firefox driver instance
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Test data file not found");
        }   
    }

    public static  void runTest(String name,String mailid) throws InterruptedException 
    {       
        System.out.println("Inputing name: "+name+" and mailid: "+mailid);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).clear();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(name);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(mailid);

        System.out.println("Inputted name: "+name+" and mailid: "+mailid);

        Thread.sleep(2000); // Sleeping 2 seconds so that each entry is detected.

    }
}
```